# How can i include a content into the email body before sending it out in android?

Tags: android, email

Hi all how can i include a content into the email body before sending it out in android. There is a static  method AppLogHelper.tail(). This returns the last 50 lines of logCat file,i need to include this log content in to the email body before sending it out. Can anyone please help me for that.

my static method returns the logcat is:

```
public static String tail() {
    if(null == AppLogHelper.getInstance()) 
        return("");
    StringBuilder sBuilder = AppLogHelper.getInstance().readLastNLog( LOG_TAIL_LINES);
    if( null != sBuilder ) 
        AppLogHelper.i("AppLogHelper", "getLogTail() sucessful");
    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

And the button to send email is:

```
public void onEmail(View v) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"support@slice.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");  
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  

    startActivity(emailIntent);   
}
```

Please help me to find a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ,

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test");
```

hope it helps you..